# Is this possible to write a post on user wall on standard facebook login?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am wonder is this possible to create app which fetch some data from external source and post it on user wall after user logged to his facebook account. Is this possible on facebook?

Comment: Your application won't be able to know whenever a user logs into Facebook - you will be able to detect a user logging into Facebook through your Facebook login implementation...

Comment: @Lix so user need to log directly to my application?

Comment: Yes - but note that people will not always login to Facebook when they log into your application. They might already have logged into Facebook before they reach your app.